# MonoTouch: Could not install sigaction override, unexpected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

My code worked in the debug mode but when I generate the ipa it gives me some problems. I have already searched a lot on the internet, some say that I should add a permission to info.plist. I put the permissions, but I don't really know what's going on.

Can someone help me? Thanks

The detailed error follows.

MonoTouch: Could not install sigaction override, unexpected sigaction implementation.
2021-01-29 13:02:11.014001-0500 EventosApp.Mobile.iOS[24184:331227]
Unhandled Exception:
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: No embeddedresource found for EventosApp.Mobile.App
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType) [0x00028] in :0
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in :0
at EventosApp.Mobile.App.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <97791f1b4d5a4feda12894e59571d501>:0
at EventosApp.Mobile.App..ctor () [0x00006] in <97791f1b4d5a4feda12894e59571d501>:0
at EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0000f] in <321e20e7a286419f9d7adc0ae75f71e4>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in <5e58267d9bbe4b28bbf05fcedb71d37a>:0
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in <5e58267d9bbe4b28bbf05fcedb71d37a>:0
at EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <321e20e7a286419f9d7adc0ae75f71e4>:0
2021-01-29 13:02:11.015134-0500 EventosApp.Mobile.iOS[24184:331227] Unhandled managed exception: No embeddedresource found for EventosApp.Mobile.App (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException)
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType) [0x00028] in :0
at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in :0
at EventosApp.Mobile.App.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <97791f1b4d5a4feda12894e59571d501>:0
at EventosApp.Mobile.App..ctor () [0x00006] in <97791f1b4d5a4feda12894e59571d501>:0
at EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0000f] in <321e20e7a286419f9d7adc0ae75f71e4>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in <5e58267d9bbe4b28bbf05fcedb71d37a>:0
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in <5e58267d9bbe4b28bbf05fcedb71d37a>:0
at EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <321e20e7a286419f9d7adc0ae75f71e4>:0

## =================================================================
Native Crash Reporting

## Got a abrt while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.

## =================================================================
Native stacktrace:

```
0x10a6bb185 - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info
0x10a6af60e - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash
0x10a6ba79f - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : sigabrt_signal_handler
0x7fff60c815fd - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
0x10abeef90 - Unknown
0x7fff200fab94 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib : abort
0x10a8dcc5f - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler
0x10a771605 - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook
0x10a6af01a - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : mono_handle_exception_internal
0x10a6ad4c9 - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : mono_handle_exception
0x10a62db59 - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : mono_amd64_throw_exception
0x10b5565b0 - Unknown
0x10a8dc9dd - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : xamarin_process_managed_exception
0x10a8e3672 - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : xamarin_invoke_trampoline
0x10a8e5832 - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : xamarin_arch_trampoline
0x10a8e61fa - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : xamarin_x86_64_common_trampoline
0x7fff2468d0f1 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:]
0x7fff2468ec73 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:]
0x7fff24694681 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]
0x7fff23cbd907 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:]
0x7fff2424bdb6 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask
0x7fff23cbe416 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke
0x7fff23cbdeda - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:]
0x7fff23cbe247 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]
0x7fff23cbdadb - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:]
0x7fff23cc5d73 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke
0x7fff241556ab - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:]
0x7fff2426865e - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext
0x7fff23cc5a79 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]
0x7fff23ae896f - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
0x7fff23ae7419 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:]
0x7fff23ae85a8 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]
0x7fff24692b20 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]
0x7fff2417dab7 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:]
0x7fff25aa20ae - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:]
0x7fff25acab41 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.176
0x7fff25aafad5 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:]
0x7fff25aca80f - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
0x7fff20106508 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : _dispatch_client_callout
0x7fff20109052 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : _dispatch_block_invoke_direct
0x7fff25af07a5 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
0x7fff25af048b - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible]
0x7fff25af0950 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
0x7fff2038f38a - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
0x7fff2038f282 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSource0
0x7fff2038e764 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSources0
0x7fff20388f2f - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopRun
0x7fff203886d6 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific
0x7fff2bededb3 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal
0x7fff24690e0b - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : -[UIApplication _run]
0x7fff24695cbc - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIApplicationMain
0x10ce26784 - Unknown
0x10ce265f3 - Unknown
0x10ce229f3 - Unknown
0x10a6c58c1 - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
0x10a7ebdf8 - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
0x10a7f2165 - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked
0x10a6246dc - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : mono_jit_exec
0x10a8e5386 - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : xamarin_main
0x10a5dea47 - /Users/user189150/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57F95219-3D4E-464D-9098-34739DFDF582/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBCFA1B5-10DE-46A1-935F-6EDA1B03EF99/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS.app/EventosApp.Mobile.iOS : main
0x7fff202593e9 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : start
0x1 - Unknown
```

## =================================================================
Basic Fault Address Reporting

Memory around native instruction pointer (0x7fff60c5833a):0x7fff60c5832a  ff ff c3 90 90 90 b8 48 01 00 02 49 89 ca 0f 05  .......H...I....
0x7fff60c5833a  73 08 48 89 c7 e9 e5 a2 ff ff c3 90 90 90 b8 53  s.H............S
0x7fff60c5834a  00 00 02 49 89 ca 0f 05 73 08 48 89 c7 e9 cd a2  ...I....s.H.....
0x7fff60c5835a  ff ff c3 90 90 90 b8 83 01 00 02 49 89 ca 0f 05  ...........I....

## =================================================================
Managed Stacktrace:

Comment: Hi, which type of provisioning file you used to deploy your project?

Comment: Why? Is there a problem associated with the type of provisioning?

Comment: Hi, the problem maybe not the provisioning file, but the error occurs when gnenrate a ipa file. I need to know the information of the provisioning file(Ad-Hoc/AppStore/Enterprise/Develop). If you select to generate a ipa, you need to check framework or library whether works with status of distribution.

Comment: thanks, my type of provisioning file is "Distribution".

Comment: Okey, do you use `MvvmCross` or other third party libraries in your project?

Comment: I do not use MvvmCross or any other "third party libraries"

Comment: Okey, form the error *No embeddedresource found for EventosApp.Mobile.App at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load*, you need to check whehter put resource files inside iOS soluton folder, not link them outside of project. And do you clean project and [**Link SDK assemblies only**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows#link-sdk-assemblies-only) to generate the ipa.